# dc leaflet - dynamic markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dc.js

I have a map built with [leaflet](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet) and [dc.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js) and integrating [dc.leaflet](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.leaflet.js/).

The data if fed via PHP to JSON and everything displays and filters without issue.
There are a variable amount of markers depending on data but somewhere around 40-50 at once and each one shows the standard Default Marker.

What I would like to do is show a different Marker based on a data field so there would be about 6 available.

This is the dc object:

```
var markerMap = dc_leaflet.markerChart(".map",group1)
    .dimension(mapDim)
    .group(mapDimGroup)
    .width(450)
    .height(630)
    .center([41.08763212467916, -77.37066651228817])
    .zoom(10)
    .cluster(false) //Turn off Clustering 
    .valueAccessor(function(kv) {return kv.value.count;})
    .locationAccessor(function(kv) {return kv.value.geo;})
    .popup(function(kv) {return kv.key;})
```

According to the Docs I should be able to use **[.icon()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dc.leaflet)**  but this doesn't seem to work.

So for example

```
if d.icon = 'icon1' then icon1.png
```

etc....

Does anybody have a any experience adding dynamic Icons?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works - it's just that Leaflet expects to see its own classes specified for icons rather than raw URLs.

Looking at the source of dc.leaflet.js, the default icon is specified like this:

```
var _icon = function(d, map) {
    return new L.Icon.Default();
};
```

Looking up this class in [the Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#icon):

> Usage example

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'my-icon.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});
```

Say we want to display octocats for all the solar installations in Bulgaria.

First, we need to change the reduction to keep the `type` field from the original data rows. This is kind of a pain, but it's the price we pay for the nice automatic reductions and filtering that crossfilter gives us:

```
  var facilitiesGroup = facilities.group().reduce(
      function(p, v) {
          p.count++;
          p.type = v.type;
          return p;
      },
      function(p, v) {
          p.count--;
          return p;
      },
      function() {
          return {count: 0, type: null};
      })
```

Now we can place the octocats wherever we see the type is solar in the reduced data. There are a lot, so let's display them at 20x20px:

```
      .icon(function(kv) {
          if(kv.value.type === 'solar')
              return L.icon({
              iconSize: [20, 20],
              iconUrl: 'https://dc-js.github.io/dc.leaflet.js/GitHub-Mark-64px.png'});
          else return new L.Icon.Default();
      })
```

Yes! We have octocatted Bulgaria!

[image: solar octocats in bulgaria]

[Example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/fLpew7r0/24/)

Comment: So can I do something like this:.icon(function(d) {
            if(d.type === 'solar') return L.icon({
              iconUrl: 'https://dc-js.github.io/dc.leaflet.js/GitHub-Mark-64px.png'
            });
            else return new L.Icon.Default();
          })

Comment: Well, okay, there are a couple of problems with that. The syntax error, and the fact that you don't have access to the raw data inside any dc chart, only the reduced data from the crossfilter group. So `d` is not a row from your data, it's a key/value pair produced by whatever reduction you are using for your group.

Comment: if I have:    var mapDimGroup = mapDim.group().reduce(
   function(p, v) { p.thing= v.thing;     ....etc then I can do:   .icon(function(kv) {
            if (kv.value.thing = "icon1")
    return L.icon({iconUrl: 'icon1.png'});
            else 
    return L.icon({iconUrl: 'icon2.png'});
   })

Comment: ok, i've updated my answer with a reduction that saves the type

Comment: Sorry, just saw your update - This does exactly what i'd hoped . Thanks for your support. Much appreciated.